Database access with Entity Framework Core not working anymore in Release but still in Debug
I have a .NET MAUI App which uses database access via Entity Framework Core 8.0.8 and SQLite. The access to this database file worked before in Release mode when I deployed my app to my iPhone 14 Pro Max, but stopped working at some time in the past. Unfortunately, I developed my app further just on simulator since May. When I tried to deploy it again, I detected it is not working anymore on my iPhone.
Currently, I still blame my switch to iOS 17.6 back then.
Anyway, I'm currently trying to re-create my app file by file and looking on what does not work anymore.
One of the things that do not work anymore is a simple line in CalculateViewModel.cs (see code below) in which I just access/query my EF Core database as follows:
var foodItems = await _databaseService.DatabaseContext.Foods.OrderBy(foodItem => foodItem.Name).ToListAsync();

Interestingly, the execution of the following line is not crashing:
var foods = _databaseService.DatabaseContext.Foods; 

But, the following line again is crashing:
var foods = _databaseService.DatabaseContext.Foods.ToList();

This line works when I start my app in Debug mode on the simulator with iOS 17.5, but doesn't when I start it Release mode on the same simulator.
My code is as follows: the code for my DbContext is defined in a separate DLL project (just a simple net8.0 DLL - non MAUI).
.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <IsAotCompatible>True</IsAotCompatible>
    <IsTrimmable>False</IsTrimmable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <IsAotCompatible>True</IsAotCompatible>
    <Optimize>True</Optimize>
    <IsTrimmable>False</IsTrimmable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.8">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" Version="8.0.8" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

DatabaseContext.cs:
using OptimizerApp.DatabaseModels;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace OptimizerApp.Database
{
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Food> Foods { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SavedMeal> SavedMeals { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FoodSelection> FoodSelections { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Comment out this method for the "dotnet ef migrations add ...> command
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="options"></param>
        public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            //DeleteDatabase();
            Database.Migrate();
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                // Use $"Data Source={""} ..." for the "dotnet ef migrations add ..." command
                //string connectionString = $"Data Source={""}";
                string connectionString = $"Filename={DatabaseConstants.DatabasePath};Mode=ReadWriteCreate";

                optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connectionString);
                optionsBuilder.EnableDetailedErrors(true);

                base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            }
        }

        public void DeleteDatabase()
        {
            File.Delete(DatabaseConstants.DatabasePath);
        }
    }
}

DatabaseConstants.cs:
namespace OptimizerApp
{
    public static class DatabaseConstants
    {
        public static string AppDataDirectory;

        public static string DatabasePath => Path.Combine(AppDataDirectory, "OptimizerDatabaseSQLite.db3");
    }
}

.\Models\Food.cs:
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace OptimizerApp.DatabaseModels
{
    [Index(nameof(Name), IsUnique = true)]
    public class Food : ObservableObject
    {
        [Key]                                                               // Primary Key will already be indexed in a Table
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        #region Name
        private string _name;

        [Required]
        [Column(Order = 2, TypeName = "TEXT COLLATE NOCASE")]              // Ignore case sensitivity for the Unique Constraint
        public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set => SetProperty(ref _name, value);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Brand
        private string? _brand;

        [Column(Order = 3)]
        public string? Brand
        {
            get => _brand;
            set => SetProperty(ref _brand, value);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}

.\Migrations: in this folder, I have my EF migrations file named 20240822153350_InitialCreate.cs which I also created again yesterday.
Relevant parts of my .NET MAUI Project which reference the database DLL project:
.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios</TargetFrameworks>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>OptimizerApp</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <!--<UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>-->
        <MauiVersion>8.0.80</MauiVersion>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>Optimizer App</ApplicationTitle>
        
        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.companyname.optimizerapp</ApplicationId>
        <ApplicationIdGuid>34a6d72a-38ef-4762-a46f-2f203727f7ce</ApplicationIdGuid>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">14.2</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net8.0-ios'">
        <EnableAssemblyILStripping>false</EnableAssemblyILStripping>
        <CodesignKey>Apple Development: Created via API (AZM52GTF9G)</CodesignKey>
        <CodesignProvision>VS Codesign Provisioning Profile</CodesignProvision>
        <ProvisioningType>manual</ProvisioningType>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <!-- Disable Trimming for DevExpress on Android/iOS -->
    <PropertyGroup>
        <DXConfigureTrimming>false</DXConfigureTrimming>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <!-- Debug / Release configurations see -->
    <!-- https://docs.devexpress.com/MAUI/404979/common-concepts/build-configuration?utm_source=SupportCenter&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=docs-feedback&utm_content=T1245248#devexpress-build-settings -->
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
        <MtouchUseLlvm>false</MtouchUseLlvm>
        <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>
        <!--<MtouchInterpreter>all</MtouchInterpreter>-->
        <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
        <MtouchUseLlvm>true</MtouchUseLlvm>
        <!--<UseInterpreter>false</UseInterpreter>-->
        <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>
        <!--<MtouchInterpreter>all</MtouchInterpreter>-->
        <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <!-- Release Build Debugging with iOS Simulator -->
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
        <RuntimeIdentifier>iossimulator-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
        <Optimize>false</Optimize>
        <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
        <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
        <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>
        <MtouchUseLlvm>false</MtouchUseLlvm>
        <MtouchNoSymbolStrip>true</MtouchNoSymbolStrip>
        <MtouchDebug>True</MtouchDebug>
        <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.png" Resize="True" BaseSize="300,185" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Splashscreen for Android -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="Pages\Views\BottomSheetContentView.xaml">
          <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
        </None>
        <None Update="Resources\Splash\mo_splash.png" Color="#000000" BaseSize="1024,1024" Resize="false" />
        <None Update="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.80" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.80" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Diagnostics" Version="8.2.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="9.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.2.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Refractored.MvvmHelpers" Version="1.6.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Maui.Core" Version="24.1.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView" Version="24.1.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="LocalizationResourceManager.Maui" Version="1.2.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.8" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.8">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="8.0.8" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" Version="8.0.8" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.8">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Sharpnado.Tabs.Maui" Version="3.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Sentry" Version="4.10.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Sentry.Maui" Version="4.10.2" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\OptimizerDatabase\OptimizerDatabase.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Update="Resources\Localization\AppResources.Designer.cs">
        <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
        <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
        <DependentUpon>AppResources.resx</DependentUpon>
      </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\Localization\AppResources.resx">
        <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
        <LastGenOutput>AppResources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>    

</Project>

MauiProgram.cs:
using CommunityToolkit.Maui;
using DevExpress.Maui;
using LocalizationResourceManager.Maui;
using OptimizerApp.Database;
using OptimizerApp.Helpers;
using OptimizerApp.Pages;
using OptimizerApp.Pages.Views;
using OptimizerApp.Resources.Localization;
using OptimizerApp.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Sharpnado.Tabs;
using XGENO.Maui.Controls;

namespace OptimizerApp
{
    public static partial class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
                .UseLocalizationResourceManager(settings =>
                {
                    settings.AddResource(AppResources.ResourceManager);
                    settings.RestoreLatestCulture(true);
                })
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                });

#if DEBUG
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

            // Configuration should occur before creating the DatabaseContext to ensure a valid AppDataDirectory is set
            DatabaseConstants.AppDataDirectory = GetDatabasePath();
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton);                       
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IErrorHandlingService, ErrorHandlingService>();

            // Build the service provider to access registered services
            var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var dbContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>();
            var errorHandlingService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IErrorHandlingService>();
            var databaseService = new DatabaseService(dbContext, errorHandlingService);
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDatabaseService>(databaseService);

            builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPage>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPageViewModel>();

            builder.Services.AddTransient<CalculateView>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<CalculateViewModel>();

            DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView.Initializer.Init();

            ConfigurePlatformServices(builder);

            var app = builder.Build();


            ServiceHelper.Initialize(app.Services);

            return app;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// // Defines a method that will be implemented in the platform specific files
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="builder">Builder to register platform specific services</param>
        static partial void ConfigurePlatformServices(MauiAppBuilder builder);

        public static string GetDatabasePath()
        {
            var databasePath = FileSystem.AppDataDirectory;

            SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init();

            // Ensure the directory exists; create it if it doesn't
            if (!Directory.Exists(databasePath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(databasePath);
            }

            return databasePath;
        }
    }
}

DatabaseService.cs:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;

namespace OptimizerApp.Database
{
    public class DatabaseService : IDatabaseService
    {
        private readonly DatabaseContext _dbContext;

        private readonly IErrorHandlingService _errorHandlingService;

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public DatabaseContext DatabaseContext { get => _dbContext; }

        public DatabaseService(DatabaseContext dbContext, IErrorHandlingService errorHandlingService)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
            _errorHandlingService = errorHandlingService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(errorHandlingService));
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public bool SaveChanges()
        {
            try
            {
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException updateException)
            {
                _errorHandlingService.HandleDatabaseError(updateException);
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _errorHandlingService.HandleGeneralError(ex);
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        private void RestoreOriginalChanges(List<IGrouping<EntityState, EntityEntry>> originalStates)
        {
            foreach (var state in originalStates)
            {
                foreach (var entry in state)
                {
                    entry.State = state.Key;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

ServiceHelper.cs:
namespace OptimizerApp.Helpers
{
    public static class ServiceHelper
    {
        public static IServiceProvider Services { get; private set; }

        public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => Services = serviceProvider;

        public static T GetService<T>() => Services.GetService<T>();
    }
}

CalculateViewModel: a calculate View uses the CalculateViewModel and contains the relevant calls and finally the line which does not work anymore in Release mode and just crashes the app without getting into a catch block when I wrap it around this line
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Messaging;
using OptimizerApp.Database;
using OptimizerApp.DatabaseModels;
using OptimizerApp.Helpers;
using OptimizerApp.Resources.Localization;
using OptimizerApp.ViewModels.Messages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MvvmHelpers;

namespace OptimizerApp.ViewModels
{
    public partial class CalculateViewModel : CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel.ObservableObject
    {
        private IDatabaseService _databaseService;
        private IErrorHandlingService _errorHandlingService;
        // ...

        public CalculateViewModel()
        {
            // Subscribe to notifications, e.g. from ManageFoodItemViewModel
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<RefreshDataBaseMessage>(this, HandleDatabaseChangedMessage);
            // ...
            
            _databaseService = ServiceHelper.GetService<IDatabaseService>();
            _errorHandlingService = ServiceHelper.GetService<IErrorHandlingService>();
            // ...

            _ = RefreshDatabase();
        }

        private async void HandleDatabaseChangedMessage(object recipient, RefreshDataBaseMessage foodItemMessage)
        {
            await RefreshDatabase();
        }
        
        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task RefreshDatabase()
        {
            await LoadAvailableFoodItems();
            await CollectSelectedFoodItems();
        }

        private async Task CollectSelectedFoodItems()
        {
            // ...
        }

        // ...
        
        private async Task LoadAvailableFoodItems()
        {
            // These line also do not work in Release
            //var count = await _databaseService.DatabaseContext.Foods.CountAsync();
            //var a = await _databaseService.DatabaseContext.Foods.ToListAsync();
            
            // Crashes the App in Release but not in Debug!!
            var foodItems = await _databaseService.DatabaseContext.Foods.OrderBy(foodItem => foodItem.Name).ToListAsync();

            // ...
        }
    }
}

Info.plist:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>arm64</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Assets.xcassets/appicon.appiconset</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen.storyboard</string>
    <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
        <string>en</string>
        <string>de</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
</dict>
</plist>

I tried around with setting <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter> and setting <MtouchUseLlvm>true</MtouchUseLlvm> both true/false but without success.
Does anybody have a clue why this line works in Debug but doesn't in Release. In Debug it successfully returns a List which does not contain any element as the Database was just deleted and migrated and is therefore still empty.
To repeat myself the entire App worked before with the exact same code on my iPhone before May. Something must have changed since then destroying this code. Or is there anything I now have to add to my Info.plist file to get it to work in Release?
Any ideas, what I could try again?
====== Update 1: Successful deploy on iPhone, Releasae debugging still crashing ======
In the meantime, I could at least deploy it to my iPhone and at least launch the App up to the part I posted here without crash.
The configuration I used for this in my .csproj was as follows:
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <RunAOTCompilation>true</RunAOTCompilation>
    <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>
    <MtouchUseLlvm>false</MtouchUseLlvm>
</PropertyGroup>

But, Release debugging on iOS Simulator still did not work, even with changed configuration:
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
    <RuntimeIdentifier>iossimulator-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>
    <MtouchUseLlvm>false</MtouchUseLlvm>
    <MtouchDebug>true</MtouchDebug>
    <RunAOTCompilation>true</RunAOTCompilation>
    <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DefineConstants>RELEASE;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <MtouchLinkSkip>Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite;Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core;MacroOptimizerDatabase;MacroOptimizerApp.Database</MtouchLinkSkip>
    <HotReloadEnabled>false</HotReloadEnabled>
</PropertyGroup>

====== Update 2: Same issue, different place ======
Now, I have the same issue at a different place also App just disappears on iPhone. Unfortunately, I can't try to debug in Release to this point as I can't get over the first line that had this problem when I try to debug on my iPad Simulator with iOS 17.5. Unfortunately, the only 17.5 Simulator, I can get is the iPad, not the iPhone Simulator. Sorry for that.
But, this crash from the Sentry analysis is from my local iPhone:

====== Update 3: Change name and Namespace ======
Today, I wanted to prepare a minimal example project. Therefore, I did the following:

Made a copy of my App
Changed the Name and Namespace to a new name
Replaced every old Name in the Solution to the new one (Find & Replace)
Changed my <ApplicationTitle>...</ApplicationTitle>, my <ApplicationId>...</ApplicationId> and my <ApplicationIdGuid>...</ApplicationIdGuid>
Deleted MacOS caches via CCleaner, bin/obj folders in the App folder
Deployed to my iPhone

I was really astonished when I started my App on my iPhone and it did not crash! How can this be explained?
I thought, maybe I should just chose a new <ApplicationTitle>, <ApplicationId> and <ApplicationIdGuid> in the original App.
But, when I did it, it still crashed
Have to say, the Namespaces still stayed the original ones
How can this be explained? Are there still left-overs from my previous developments before the iOS Update in May? Or are there any folders on the Mac that still have the old App DLLs? (this would not make sense, when it was renamed and got a new GUID)
Or is my original App just identified by the Namespace which was still the old one and there is a conflict there? Can iOS block something or anywhere else something that blocks it?
I am just guessing, but this is really curious.
Any ideas or explanations?

Review the code changes you did in the mean time. Most likely the culprit is somewhere in there.

There was no change in this file, that is the interesting part. I updated NuGet-Packages, but also switching back to the old ones is crashing now. Therefore, my guess is that the iOS update could have brought changes so that this line doesn't work anymore in Release. The interesting part is also that there is absolutely no problem in Debug

Probably the first thing would be what are you doing for logging output at runtime? You have an error handling service in your DbContext wrapper, but your read is just going straight through to the DbContext. If this happens to be the first read, you could have an issue with the model creation.
Consider adding a model validation to your service:
    public DatabaseService(DatabaseContext dbContext, IErrorHandlingService errorHandlingService)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
        _errorHandlingService = errorHandlingService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(errorHandlingService));

        validateModel();
    }

    private void validateModel()
    {
        try
        {
            var model = dbContext.Model;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _errorHandlingService.HandleGeneralError(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

Accessing the .Model will ensure the model compiles. If that works without an error/crash then it may be specific to the schema/read. Do other data read operations work? Try reading a different entity, getting a Count(), etc. Basically employ a process of elimination.
As a worst case, do you have a global exception handler? This likely won't be able to use your Error Handling Service, but employ something lower level. It should be enough to capture a crash if a try/catch isn't working.

I checked if I can get the model as you propsed in the line right before the access that crashes and I got a valid instance! The line that crashes is really the first read access as you mentioned. Interestingly, the execution of var foods = _databaseService.DatabaseContext.Foods; is working without crashing, but var foodsList = _databaseService.DatabaseContext.Foods.ToList(); crashes again. And I am not successful wrapping it in try-catch-Blocks as I can't debug to the Exception

Ok, getting Foods without the ToList() is just a reference to the DbSet, it won't execute a query until something iterates over it. You could try fetching something like ".Foods.First()" and try fetching some other entity, or get a ..Count(). Do you mean if you have a try/catch block your call to the error handling service doesn't get called? Verify your error handler is working by using a deliberate throw new InvalidOperationException("Test"); inside the exception handling before calling something that crashes. It does seem very odd that EF could crash without ex handling tripping.

Well, var count = _databaseService.DatabaseContext.Foods.Count(); crashes and var count = foods.Count();crashes, too (which I've expected). Crash: with crash I don't mean Exception, the App is just gone! So any kind of logging would be, too. Therefore, I used the (hopefully) debugable Release Configuration you can see in my .csproj. Even there when stepping through the code the App in Simulator is just closed. Here, it came to my mind if something is stripped or so, but I thought with the configuration I shared this should not happen. I still can't get it that it is working in Debug.

I used Sentry to get some crash information. What I can see there is a EXC_BAD_ACCESS
mono_interp_exec_method - Unhandled Exception 1, Code 1, Subcode 10448355523508796413 > Stack overflow in (null). Is there a problem with the Compiler in the end? I am using XCode 15.2 and Command Line Tools 15.1 and rund this Simulator Debugging Session with Release Build on a 17.5 Simulator. But also tried on 16.4 Simulator which also crashes the App at the same point. Any other ideas so that maybe Code is optimized away. I would not expect this with my settings from the .csproj or wrong?

I also checked that my Database file is available in the directory via FileSystem.AppDataDirectory which is /Users/mauioxo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F12F6514-9076-4074-8DB2-BB8FC867FBF7/data/Containers/Data/Application/91619C1B-7163-42CB-A694-69F43D3997B8/Library and in there I see my .db3 file. An when I look into it with a DB Editor on my Mac, all the tables are available from a fresh migration and are empty as expected. I added a simple Entry to it and even then this access doesn't work

Ouch, One thing you can try is creating a basic Food entity, one that does not extend ObservableObject, and create a simple test DbContext binding a DbSet to that entity, then in a test try reading data through it. Multi-purposing entities as view models is not something I recommend and a stack overflow exception smells of something getting hung in a cycle for some reason. If it were the model layout then the call to get context.Model would have raised an exception.

I tried that, and to make it easier, I opted out notifications for changes in the Foods data model. Well, then I got a different message in Sentry **System.AggregateException: TaskExceptionHolder_UnhandledException** - icrosoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Foods'.. I even deleted the entire app from the Simulator and created a new Initial Migration with it. Did not work with it successfully. But, when I used the configuration I updated my question with, I could start at least now start my App on my iPhone! Debugging it in Release on Simulator did not work

Some thoughts: we could argue that I could finally deploy the code I shared to my iPhone and start the App. Yes, true! On the one hand, I am currently re-creating my App as more parts seemed to be not working anymore when deployed after May. Therefore, I was re-creating my App file by file until I hit another problem and debug it. So, I am pretty sure I would still need to debug it on iOS Simulator deployed as Release. The problem right now also seems to be a problem of my debugable Release configuration. Regarding ObserableObjects: how could I achive to notify when Foods change?

Now, I have the same error obviously at a different line of code (see my Update 2 in my original question). I can't debug to this line in Release Mode on iOS Simulator. Would it help to prepare a little project for you to have a look at and if you see any stupid thing I am doing or that I missed so far and to see it on your iPhone? Or if you are able to debug in Release mode to have a look? Or do you have any further ideas with this Sentry report snippet?

Please see my new findings in Update 3 within my original question. Is there an explanation for that and solution?
